# Check if a binary tree is a binary search tree - Why doesn't my code work?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

You are given the root of a binary tree and you must check if it's a binary search tree. Note that the value of all nodes are distinct (It's a question from Hackerrank in the Trees section). [This](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-is-binary-search-tree/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=trees) is the link

I really can't figure out why my code doesn't work. Makes no sense.

Here's my code in java

```
boolean checkBST(Node root) {
    if(root == null) return false; // could be true or false I guess?
    if(root.left == null && root.right == null) return true;

    if(root.left != null && root.right != null) return checkBST(root.left) && checkBST(root.right) && root.left.data < root. data && root.right.data > root.data;

    if(root.left != null) return checkBST(root.left) && root.left.data < root.data;
    if(root.right != null) return checkBST(root.right) && root.right.data > root.data;

    return false;
}
```

The code runs but it fails at this test case:

2
1 2 4 3 5 6 7

It outputs yes instead of No. Also I'm not sure how they are building the trees from the array unfortunately but it shouldn't matter.

My questions:

1. Why doesn't my code work?
2. Is my first base case correct? I set it to false in an attempt to make it more challenging
3. If have so many if statements and is that good code or bad code? Do you recommend using if-else statements?

Thank you

Comment: guys this is in Java ! There's is no error code. It just fails at this test case and I'm guessing many more

2
1 2 4 3 5 6 7

It outputs yes instead of No. I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in how you only check that the condition only holds for the immediate children and not the entire left and right subtrees.  You can see the issue with your code visually with this example.

```
    3
   / \
  2   5
 / \
1   4
```

You can see that the `4` node is greater than its parent, but it is not less than its grandparent.  However, this should not be the case since every node to the left of the `3` should be less than three.

The problem states that for every node, the left descendents must be less than that node and the right descendents must be greater than that node.  What you need to do is keep track of a min and max value a node can take.

```
boolean checkBST(Node root) {
  return checkBST(node, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}

boolean checkBST(Node root, int min, int max) {
  if(root == null) return true;
  if(root.data < min || root.data > max) return false;

  return checkBST(root.left, min, root.data) && checkBST(root.right, root.data, max);
}
```

We're returning `true` in the case that `root` is `null` because it's easier that way when we don't need to check that the left and right nodes aren't `null` before calling `checkBST` on them.  The next thing you need to check is that `root`'s value falls within the valid range.  And the last step is to check that all the children's values fall in their correct ranges as well.  The left descendents must all be less than the root, and the right descendents must all be greater than the root.  So for checking the left children, we make the root's value the max, and for the right children we make the root's value the min.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much